# Shell Script failing to run a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a debian server set up with mounted drives from google drive - these sometimes get unmounted, so I have made a script to check for, and remount, unmounted drives.

The script will check against a file in the mounted directory and if it's missing it will attempt to remount the drive.

It will succesfully check all mounts, but is only able to remount "plexdrive" and "plexlib" it fails to mount "decrypt".

There is nothing wrong with the mounting command as it works fine outside of the script.

The script in question:

```
#!/bin/bash
## Small hack that makes this script work in cronjob
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home22/krealle/check.rclone.mount
## Logfile
LOGFILE=~/log/check-mounts.log
## Variables
Errors=0
## create $LOGFILE
if [ ! -f $LOGFILE ]; then
    touch $LOGFILE
    echo "INFO: Logfile created." >> $LOGFILE
fi
echo "" >> $LOGFILE
echo "$(date "+%d/%m/%Y %T")"  >> $LOGFILE
## Ultimate Check - Smaller log file!
if [[ -f /home22/krealle/mounts/plexdrive/plexdrive_mounted ]] && [[ -f /home22/krealle/mounts/plexdrive-decrypt/mounted ]] && [[ -f /home22/krealle/PlexMedia/PlexLib/mounted ]]; then
    echo "INFO: Errors found: $Errors - skipping individual checks." >> $LOGFILE
    exit
fi
## check plexdrive mount
if [[ -f /home22/krealle/mounts/plexdrive/plexdrive_mounted ]]; then
    echo "INFO: *Plexdrive* Mountcheck successful." >> $LOGFILE
else
    echo "ERROR: *Plexdrive* Drive not mounted remount in progress." >> $LOGFILE
    ## first unmount broken/busy remotes.
    fusermount -zu /home22/krealle/mounts/plexdrive

    ## Mount Plexdrive.
    screen -S  plexdrive.s: -d -m ./plexdrive -o allow_other -v 4 /home22/krealle/mounts/plexdrive

    if [[ -f /home22/krealle/mounts/plexdrive/plexdrive_mounted ]]; then
        echo "INFO: *Plexdrive* Remount successful." >> $LOGFILE
    else
        ((Errors++))
        echo "CRITICAL: *Plexdrive* Remount failed." >> $LOGFILE
    fi
fi
## check decrypt mount
if [[ -f /home22/krealle/mounts/plexdrive-decrypt/mounted ]]; then
    echo "INFO: *Plexdrive-Decrypt* Mountcheck successful." >> $LOGFILE
else
    echo "ERROR: *Plexdrive-Decrypt* Drive not mounted remount in progress." >> $LOGFILE
    ## first unmount broken/busy remotes.
    fusermount -zu /home22/krealle/mounts/plexdrive-decrypt

    ## Mount Plexdrive-decrypt.
    screen -S rclone.decrypt: -d -m rclone mount --read-only --allow-non-empty --allow-other --buffer-size 128M -v plexdrive2: /home22/krealle/mounts/plexdrive-decrypt

    if [[ -f /home22/krealle/mounts/plexdrive-decrypt/mounted ]]; then
        echo "INFO: *Plexdrive-Decrypt* Remount successful." >> $LOGFILE
    else
        ((Errors++))
        echo "CRITICAL: *Plexdrive-Decrypt* Remount failed." >> $LOGFILE
    fi
fi
## check plexlib mount
if [[ -f /home22/krealle/PlexMedia/PlexLib/mounted ]]; then
    echo "INFO: *PlexLib* Mountcheck successful." >> $LOGFILE
else
    echo "ERROR: *PlexLib* Drive not mounted remount in progress." >> $LOGFILE
    ## first unmount broken/busy remotes.
    fusermount -zu /home22/krealle/PlexMedia/PlexLib

    ## Mount PlexLib.
    unionfs-fuse -o cow,allow_other,direct_io,nonempty,auto_cache,sync_read /home22/krealle/PlexMedia/Local=RW:/home22/krealle/mounts/plexdrive-decrypt=RO /home22/krealle/PlexMedia/PlexLib

    if [[ -f /home22/krealle/PlexMedia/PlexLib/mounted ]]; then
        echo "INFO: *PlexLib* Remount successful." >> $LOGFILE
    else
        ((Errors++))
        echo "CRITICAL: *PlexLib* Remount failed." >> $LOGFILE
    fi
fi
echo "Total errors: $Errors " >> $LOGFILE
```

My script is based on the one found [here.](https://kb.ultraseedbox.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6586407)

Comment: Try debugging the script with -x to begin with

Comment: Thank you! That will come in handy a lot!